# Ionic 3: $dirty button reveal

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, ionic-framework

I would like my "Save" button to only show up/be available for click, if data is entered in the form. I can't figure out the logic of it, but here is what I have done so far:

**HTML file:**

```
<ion-list>
    <ion-item>
        <ion-label>City Name:</ion-label>
        <ion-input name="City" placeholder="City"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>

    <ion-item>
        <ion-label>State Name:</ion-label>
        <ion-input name="state" placeholder="state"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>

</ion-list>

<button ion-button *ngIf="dirty == true" (click)="saveChanges()> Save </button>
```

I believe the issue lies in the `<button>` tag

Answer (score 0):

you can use two approaches for this thing 
i> reactive angular form (https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms)
ii> use onchange on input and check they have valid data

> *ngIf ="dirty" // in view

and make the dirty flag as true when form is proper filled.

Answer (score 0):

You should trigger a check function which will check if both inputs arent empty

**.HTML file**

```
<ion-list>
    <ion-item>
        <ion-label>City Name:</ion-label>
        <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="city" (ionChange)="change();" placeholder="city"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>

    <ion-item>
        <ion-label>State Name:</ion-label>
        <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="state" (ionChange)="change();" placeholder="state"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>

</ion-list>

<button ion-button *ngIf="dirty == true" (click)="saveChanges()> Save </button>
```

**.ts file**

```
    export class <YOUR_CLASS> {

    city;
    state;

    constructor {...}

   change() {
    if (this.city !== "" && this.state !== "") {
       //Enable button
    }

    }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I just had a quick question though- I'm planning on adding more inputs in the list, so instead of having the (ionChange) function on each of the inputs, would this method still work if I put the (ionChange) function in the <ion-list> tags instead?